# On Mac OSX, how can I open a deleted file which is still open by a process?

Tags: osx, deleted-files

```
b2-osx108v8-01:~ bamboo$ lsof -p 264
COMMAND PID   USER   FD     TYPE            DEVICE  SIZE/OFF     NODE NAME
<lines removed>
java    264 bamboo   20w     REG               1,2    240906 14883372 /Users/bamboo/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/ST-SSINR-B2OSML/SimbaProcessManager.log.0
<lines removed>
```

The `/Users/bamboo/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/ST-SSINR-B2OSML` directory has already been deleted, but the file is still open by our daemon process. How can I look at this log? On Linux, I'd use `/proc/264/fd/20`, but that doesn't seem to be available on OSX.

Answer (score 5):

<EDIT>

If this was Linux, you could also use a `gdb` trick.  But it turns out we can rule out that trick on OS X, because it relies on Linux-specific behaviour of `/dev/fd/` (`/proc/self/fd/`).

That's all I know, I don't have a positive suggestion.

</EDIT>

It could go horribly horribly wrong, but have you considered `gdb`?  Two miracles in one package: a C interpreter, and a way to inject code into the process of your choice!  Apparently you can also use it for debugging.

Fortunately the C standard library also includes a function which interprets scripts. The scripting language on your platform might be more convenient to write than C...

I thought of a script which uses `less` for OS X. This is a fragile hack to seek back to the start of the logfile based on [OS X, bash: less works on open file descriptors, cat doesn't](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/209620/os-x-bash-less-works-on-open-file-descriptors-cat-doesnt) After reading the whole log file with `less`, the FD position should be at the end of the file, which is hopefully the original position before we meddled with it.

<EDIT>But it only works if the file was also opened for reading.  According to your `lsof` output, the file was only open for writing.</EDIT>

```
gdb -p 264 <<EOF
call (int) system("exec </dev/null >/tmp/log 2>&1; less /dev/fd/20")
EOF
```

I cast the return type, because otherwise my system complained that it did not know the return type of `system()`. Presumably this also means that it wasn't sure of the argument types either, so this is already sounding like such a great idea.

Using `system()` to manipulate file descriptors somehow worked when I tried it on my Linux box... once.  I don't promise it will always work :).  E.g., technically this is not guaranteed to be safe if the program is executing a signal handler, or indeed `system()` itself.  (`system()` is not one of the few functions which is guaranteed to be "re-entrant").

Comment: This _seems_ to have worked, although the created file is empty (not sure if any output was still buffered in the process, it was empty for other reasons, or the `cat` somehow failed, which seems unlikely)

Comment: @Bwmat ah. hmm. I didn't test this quite properly. I think it will fail because the file is only open for writing (and probably won't seek back to the start of the file anyway?).  So I suspect this can't be made to work.

Comment: @Bwmat I have revised my command to include some error handling :). Still not tested.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas edited, thanks. Huh, I thought `2>&1` was standard sh, so `<&20` would also be.

Comment: @Bwmat I have edited again. `/dev/fd/N` on Linux seems to seek to the start, and allow re-opening for reading. Pretty sure Mac OS also has /dev/fd/N, maybe the same thing works.

Comment: You can only use fds 0 to 9 portably in x<&y.

Comment: opening `/dev/fd/n` on Linux opens the file pointed by the fd anew. You get a new and unrelated open file description. It's not doing the same as a `dup()` like on other systems.

Comment: Can we seek on the FD in sh?

Comment: @Bwmat I think I found a way (edited)

Comment: @Bwmat, you can seek in zsh and ksh93, not plain sh. You can always call perl to do the `seek`, but in any case, that won't help if the file has been open in write-only mode.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas which of course it isn't (lsof `w` marker).  Ho hum.

Comment: on OSX, can you re-open a file by-fd?

Comment: The script also works with lldb, in case you are on Apple Silicon where gdb isn't available as of 2022. [(via)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67310123)

Answer (score 0):

I have not verified that `icat` behaves correctly when operating on a block device, nor that Mac OS has block devices, nor whether doing the below will EAT YOUR DATA.

It might be possible to use `icat /dev/MY-DEVICE 14883372`. The `icat` command is provided by The Sleuth Kit® (TSK).

https://github.com/sleuthkit/sleuthkit/wiki/HFS

(You already mentioned Linux.  This idea was inspired by `debugfs`, which has a command to do the same thing for the Linux filesystems ext2/ext3/ext4).